# Javascript: Accessing JSON properties with identical names?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to access "15.00" in the following partial JSON, but "undefined is not an object" error if I use object.shipping.rates.rate.amount. I think what's tripping me up is the JSON contains two "region_code"s and when I call for that property Javascript doesn't know which one to give me. And I don't know how to tell it I want the one associated with "US_CON" region_code. How can I specify? Thanks.

```
"shipping": {
        "free_expedited_shipping": false,
        "local": false,
        "rates": [
          {
            "region_code": "US_CON",
            "rate": {
              "amount": "15.00",
              "amount_cents": 1500,
              "currency": "USD",
              "symbol": "$",
              "display": "$15"
            }
          },
          {
            "region_code": "XX",
            "rate": {
              "amount": "50.00",
              "amount_cents": 5000,
              "currency": "USD",
              "symbol": "$",
              "display": "$50"
            }
```

Comment: Rates is an array. So use `object.shipping.rates[i].rate.amount`, where `i` is some index.

Comment: please provide the javascript you are using to access this

Comment: why not do a condition check on `region_code`. if `region_code == 'US_CON'` then then get `rate.amount`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json/11922384#11922384

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`object.shipping.rates` is an array. You would not be able to access it like that.

Please use indexing or looping.

Indexing

```
console.log(object.shipping.rates[0].rate.amount)
```

Looping

```
Object.keys(object.shipping.rates).map(key => {
   console.log(object.shipping.rates[key].rate.amount)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find` to get the region of which the region_code is US_CON.

```js
var shipping = {
  "free_expedited_shipping": false,
  "local": false,
  "rates": [
    {
      "region_code": "US_CON",
      "rate": {
        "amount": "15.00",
        "amount_cents": 1500,
        "currency": "USD",
        "symbol": "$",
        "display": "$15"
      }
    },
    {
      "region_code": "XX",
      "rate": {
        "amount": "50.00",
        "amount_cents": 5000,
        "currency": "USD",
        "symbol": "$",
        "display": "$50"
      }
    }
  ]
};

const region = shipping.rates.find(r => r.region_code == 'US_CON');
console.log(region.rate.amount);
```